# Appending raspberry pi routing table with a new label

Tags: networking

I am working on setting up a VLAN network made up by 2 nodes. each consisting of multiple raspberry pis and a switch. For this purpose, I need to add a VLAN tag to the routing table of the raspberry pis. There is a lot of documentation about how to make changes to the routing table when adding a new entry, but only under the default labels such as gateway, interface, metric, flag, etc. What I wish to know is how to add a new label alongside the ones mentioned above.
It would be great if anyone could help me with this.

---

@Ingo

Thank you for your answer.
By routing table, I mean the table that we get after entering the following command:

> route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway   Genmask        Flags Metric Ref  Use   Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1  0.0.0.0       UG    202    0      0       eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0   U     202    0    0       eth0
```

I apologize for not making my question clear. I understand that `gateway, interface, metric flag` etc are properties but I wanted to know if I could add one more column for the VLAN ID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't specific to Raspberry Pi. Anyway, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. The items `gateway, interface, metric, flag` etc. are not simply labels on a table. They are properties of the routing mechanism. And what routing table do you mean? Mine has no labels:

```
rpi3 ~$  ip route
default via 192.168.10.2 dev vlan10 proto static
192.168.7.0/24 dev vlan7 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.7.1
192.168.10.0/24 dev vlan10 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1
192.168.20.0/24 dev vlan20 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.20.1
```

For using VLAN you have to specify what VLANs your interface is connected to

```
rpi3 ~$ ip addr   # stripped to relevant info
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:1c:38:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: vlan20@ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:1c:38:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.1/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global vlan20
4: vlan10@ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:1c:38:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.1/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global vlan10
    inet 192.168.10.10/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global secondary vlan10
5: vlan7@ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:1c:38:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.7.1/24 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global vlan7
```

and then you can route to the `Virtual LANs` like with normal interfaces. Look at my routing table. That's how routing to VLANs work.

For showing the routing table with old style `route` it isn't possible to add a column labeled *"VLAN"* but it isn't needed. The `vlanX` is shown in column *"Iface"*. `VLANs` have normal (virtual) interfaces:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.2    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan10
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vlan7
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vlan10
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vlan20
```

Comment: Since I couldn't add the routing table in the comment in the proper format, I had to post the comment as an answer. I would really appreciate any input you can provide.

Comment: @Doe.John Editing the question is the right way. I have updated my answer for old style `route`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. Also, I'm fairly new here and this was my first question, so I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Does the answer meets your question? So you can accept it to finalize it. And yes, to take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) is also a good thing ;-)